# Is it possible to upload a document from SharePoint Mobile site?

Tags: document-library, mobile

I need a function to upload few documents to my SharePoint 2010 mobile site using a mobile browser. But I do not see the function anywhere. Anyone knows how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

On a windows mobile , there are some enhanced activeX controls for IE that supports SP 2010 ribbon upload functionality.

Let us know , what mobile and browser type you are using.

Comment: I am using either Android, iPhone or Blackberry. Any solutions for that?

Comment: Please try with firefox on Android

Comment: Its working with FF on Android but generally many mobile browsers are incompatible with SP site